# How to handle exception raised in linq

Tags: c#, linq, exception

gyus! Suppose I have such simple LINQ expression

```
IEnumerable<StopListMatchViewModel> res =
    from rqResult in MatchesList
    select new StopListMatchViewModel
        (
        )
        {
            MatchDate = DateTime.ParseExact(rqResult.Row["MatchDate"].ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:m:ss", fmtInfo),
            Remark = rqResult.Row["Remark"].ToString()
        }
```

if string couldn't be parsed according to specified format mask - I get FormatException. In debugger I can know about it in results view of variable "res". In realtime i get empty collection.

There could be many examples of different exceptions that could happen during executiong LINQ. How could I catch and handle them? try catch block doesn't work here, because exception seems to me to not to be raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of deferred execution the query is not executed until you evaluate the query, such as by making use of the `.ToList()` method. The exception will be thrown at that time only.

To avoid the problem you need to modify the query. something as below

```
IEnumerable<StopListMatchViewModel> res =
    from rqResult in MatchesList
    select new StopListMatchViewModel
    {
        MatchDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
            ((rqResult.Row["MatchDate"]==null) ?
                rqResult.Row["MatchDate"] : DateTime.MinValue).ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:m:ss", fmtInfo),
        Remark = rqResult.Row["Remark"].ToString()
    }
```

Note : `DateTime.MinValue` is used when the value of `rqResult.Row["MatchDate"]` is null which used to avoid null

Comment: TryParseExact is better way to avoid the exception

Answer (score 0):

Use the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method to avoid not needed exceptions.
I don't understand why you can't use the try-catch block? You really think it is not raised?
Also you should check your database for the NULL-values:

```
MatchDate = Convert.IsDBNull (rqResult.Row["MatchDate"]) ?   
  DateTime.MinValue : 
  DateTime.ParseExact(rqResult.Row["MatchDate"].ToString(),
    "dd.MM.yyyy HH:m:ss", 
    fmtInfo),
Remark = (string)rqResult.Row["Remark"] ?? String.EmptyString;
```